# Finding $\iiint_S\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\,dx\,dy\,dz$ where $S: x^2+y^2+z^2\le9 \,,\, 0\le z$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Question:

$$\iiint_S\sqrt{x^2+y^2}dxdydz$$

$$S: x^2+y^2+z^2\le9$$
$$0\le z$$

I've solved it to $\frac{81\pi^2}{8}$ by using spherical coordinates, but I got in my head that I should be able to solve it by looking at $x^2+y^2\le9$ like a circular disc with radius from 0 to 3, which is integrated over z from 0 to 3 (like I'm getting a half sphere) and then duplicating it to get the whole sphere. Something like this (when using that $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ for positive r's):

$$\int_{0}^{3}\iint\limits_{x^2+y^2\le9}(r) dxdydz$$

However, I can't get the right answer that way. What am I forgetting?

Appreciate any input.

Comment: Lower limit of double integral should be $x^2+y^2\le9-z^2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a start. You can use cylindrical coordinates

> $$ \int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{3}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{9-r^2}}r \,dz rd\,rd\theta. $$